# Magento 2 Mysql query taxvat to vat_id

Tags: mysql, sql, magento2

I migrated from magento 1.9.x to 2.2.5 and now I need to copy some taxvat information to another place to make payment gateway work correctly with guest checkout.

How can I copy **all users** customer_entity taxvat to customer_address_entity vat_id?

I was trying something like this, but not sure how to make it work.

```
INSERT INTO pku_customer_address_entity (vat_id)
SELECT taxvat FROM pku_customer_entity
WHERE entity_id = (SELECT parent_id FROM pku_customer_address_entity);
```

Answer (score 1):

If any of you guys made a Magento migration and had some TaxVat information under customer account and other in billing address and that was causing problems in checkout here is my contribution.

**Important: Make a backup of your database first**

Go do phpMyAdmin => SQL and use this to **copy** information from **taxvat (Magento 1)** to **vat_id (Magento 2)**:

UPDATE customer_address_entity,customer_entity
SET customer_address_entity.vat_id = customer_entity.taxvat
WHERE customer_address_entity.parent_id = customer_entity.entity_id